# Trying to build a json object to send to laravel. Problems with key name

Tags: php, json, angularjs, laravel

I am trying to make a key and value array to send to my laravel backend.

this is my current code

```
$http.post('../survey/'+$scope.clientID+'/getSurvey', {client: $scope.clientID }).

        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.survey_id = data[0];

            $scope.questions = data;

            //$scope.dLength = data.length;
            $scope.dLength = 5;
            console.log($scope.questions);

            // When an answer button is clicked

            $scope.clicky = function(value) {

                // Add a class to hide the div cntainng the question
                $scope.class = "hideit";

                //Set a timeout function so the question can fadeOut before we proces anything
                var callAtTimeout = function() {

                    // Check to see if this is the last question
                    if($scope.qid >= $scope.dLength -1){

                        // All questions have been answered. AJAX the data back to Laravel

                        alert("complete")

                        $http.post('../survey/'+$scope.survey_id.survey_id+'/submitSurvey', {data: angular.fromJson($scope.answers)}).
                        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log(data);
                        })
                        //})

                        //console.log($scope.answers)

                    }else{  

                        //Build up the Array of answeres

                        // Get Question name - this will be the key
                        var questionName = $scope.questions[$scope.qid].name;

                        // This is the value
                        var questionAnswer = value

                        //build the aray element
                        var line = { questionName : value };

                        //Push it to the array
                        $scope.answers.push({questionName: questionAnswer});

                        //console.log($scope.answers)

                        //add to the count variable                 
                        $scope.qid += 1;

                        // Animate the question div back up to display the next question
                        $scope.class = "showit";

                    }
                }

                $timeout(callAtTimeout, 1000)
            }

        }).
```

When I look at the data I am building it is showing questionname as the key instead of the data that is in the variable question name.

When I alert the variable question name it shows the correct data, but the array is just showing the key as "questionname", Am I building the array wrong, if so how should I be building it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you may try to build it like that:

```
var question = {};
question[questionName] = questionAnswer;
$scope.answers.push(question);
```

Also, it looks like with ECMAScript 6 it will be possible to achieve the same thing in a slightly prettier manner:

```
$scope.answers.push({ [questionName]: questionAnswer});
```

UPD:

According to the comments, you don't need to create an array, but build an object instead. It might be something like this:

```
$scope.answers = {};
// loop through the questions:
$scope.answers[questionName] = questionAnswer;
```

After that you'll be able to access answers like this:

```
var answer = $scope.answers["MyQuestionName"];
```

Comment: I think thats as close as I have got so far. That gives me an array of 3 objects. What I would like to have is a complete collection of key values so I can reference them to get the value. For example I use $array[senior_1] and that would contain the answer (the value)

Comment: @ChrisTownsend, I've updated the answer. It looks like you don't need an array at all here. Just build a simple object.